# How to eliminate an old Ubuntu partition?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, hard-drive

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit side by side with my previous 11.10 32-bit.

As everything is working correctly, I want to eliminate the old partition.

According to `update-grub`:

> Found Ubuntu 11.10 (11.10) on /dev/sda1

But according to GParted, `/dev/sda1` is the boot partition!

So, how can I discover which partition should be the boot partition for 12.04? Can I safely eliminate the `/dev/sda1`?

Also, GParted gives `/dev/sda5` as file system unknown, it's 2.93Gib and might be the swap partition (just guessing).

Comment: Do you have Windows installed in your computer?

Comment: @Anwar. No, just Ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04 as stated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these procedures:

1. Delete the `/dev/sda1` partition from Gparted
2. Create a new partition on `/dev/sda1` from Gparted and also a new file system by formatting it.
3. Open a terminal and type this command

   ```
    sudo grub-install /dev/sda
   ```
4. Then run this command:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

It should help you to get rid of that old partition.

---

<sup>1. Learn about Active partition or boot flag [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_flag)</sup>

Comment: Would it not be safer to check first with the boot flag on the correct partition?

Comment: Also, I'd like to join the two partitions. I think the new partition is on /dev/sda6

Comment: @GUIJunkie After creating a new partition, you can set boot flag in that partition by selecting it, right clicking and selecting "manage flags" from the menu. Boot flag is for a Windows OS afaik. Grub doesn't need boot flag.

Comment: @GUIJunkie You can't join the two partition if another partition exists between them. I suggest you to ask another question after doing the deletion stuff

Comment: OK, the old partition and Grub2 entry are gone :-)